# Is it safe to assume that atan2(0,0) returns 0?

Tags: python, c, atan2

It seems that`atan2(0,0)` in C is defined [this way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Realizations_of_the_function_in_common_computer_languages).  Python just delegates the common trigonometric functions to the underlying C implementation, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python docs don't explicitly specify atan2(0, 0), but the [CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Modules/mathmodule.c#L566) goes to specific effort to ensure special cases follow C99 even if the underlying C library doesn't. This includes a code path that handles making atan2(0, 0) return 0.0:

```
if (Py_IS_INFINITY(x) || y == 0.) {
    if (copysign(1., x) == 1.)
        /* atan2(+-y, +inf) = atan2(+-0, +x) = +-0. */
        return copysign(0., y);
    ...
```

In general, functions provided in the `math` module that correspond to C standard library functions are expected to match the C standard behavior. There are a few blanket statements to this effect, such as this one near the top of the docs:

> This module is always available. It provides access to the mathematical functions defined by the C standard.

and this one near the bottom:

> Behavior in exceptional cases follows Annex F of the C99 standard where appropriate.

although Annex F isn't the part of the standard that defines atan2.

Comment: Thanks. I really meant CPython, the other various implementations are not relevant to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

As @user2357112 said, docs do not specify this. If you need something well documented - use `numpy.arctan2` - see Notes section in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html

Comment: This is good advice. I often use numpy maths when necessary.

Comment: One bad thing about `numpy` functions is that they are slower than corresponding functions from the `math` library due to all the overhead associated with arrays. It is faster when applying the same operation to arrays of data.